# Can't run for loop in template literals

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to build an AJAX function that will fetch data to my html page, I learned that template literals can hold html code in variables so I started using that. I am having an error that for loop display as a text on my page

```js
    <script>
        function getForms() {
            let countryId = document.getElementById("country").value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('getServiceDocuments') }}' + '/' + countryId,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
                        $('.documents').html($('.documents').html() + `
                            <ol type="-">
                            <li> <h4>- ${data[1].country_name}</h4></li>
                                <ol>
                                <li style="margin-bottom: -10px">${data[i][0].service_name}</li>
                                     for (let j = 0; j < data[i][0].service_country_doc.length; j++) {
                                        <li style="margin-left: 105px"> -  ${data[i][0].service_country_doc[j].document.doc_title}
                                            <a href="">
                                                  <i class="i-icon-template fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                      }
                                </ol>
                            </ol>
                    `);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: *I am having an error that for loop display as html content* -- what is the error?

Comment: @AndroidNoobie for loop doesn't work I see it as text on my page

Comment: A `for` loop doesn't return anything to be interpolated into your string. Trying to do this all inline is just going to make your code unmanageable. Build up your HTML strings (or even better, create real DOM elements) iteratively

Comment: there is no way to make it works here? @Phil

Comment: You could potentially use `Array.prototype.map()` but that's going to get very ugly and you don't want to write ugly, unmaintainable code do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unpack the success method, I think you'll find you need to do some more string interpolation to get things working.  You currently have the `for` loop directly in the HTML string so it is not getting interpreted as javascript.  Also as pointed out in the comments, the for loop does not return anything.

Here's one possible example of trying to unpack that a little bit into helpers

```
function listEntry(data, i, j) {
  return `
          <li style="margin-left: 105px">
             -  ${data[i][0].service_country_doc[j].document.doc_title}
             <a href="">
                 <i class="i-icon-template fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </a>
          </li>`;
}

function listEntries(data, i) {
  let result = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < data[i][0].service_country_doc.length; j++) {
    result += listEntry(data, i, j)
  }
  return result;
}


$.ajax({
  ...
  success: (data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
      $('.documents').html($('.documents').html() + `
         <ol type="-">
           <li> <h4>- ${data[i].country_name}</h4></li>
           <ol>
             <li style="margin-bottom: -10px">${data[i][0].service_name}</li>
             ${listEntries(data,i)}
           </ol>
         </ol>
     `);

  })
})
```

This could certainly be further cleaned up using some `map` functions but this might get things working.